# /var/log/httpd permissions reset from 705 to 700 after reboot

Tags: permissions, rhel, selinux

After a reboot `/var/log/httpd` permissions reset from 705 to 700.

Could this be a SELinux issue?

OS is RHEL 8.

Answer (score 0):

No, SELinux has nothing to do with that.  SELinux does not modify file permissions.

700 is the default permission for the  `/var/log/httpd` directory, and is restored each time the `httpd` package is updated. Probably your machine updated the package just before reboot. If you want another permission to be set, you need to change it each time, either manually or via script.

[Source (requires a Red Hat account)](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/20970)